# Copy value From Column A to Column B within the same List when a new item is created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, copy-item

So i am fairly new to SharePoint and i have stumbled upon a problem wherein i want to copy an item in column A to Column B in the same list through a workflow  but there is only an option for copying from one list to another.

Could you please help me out in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Copy value From Column A to Column B, you can use "Set Field in Current Item" action, create a workflow like the following:

[image]

Comment: I am glad to hear it helps. Please remember to mark the helpful post as an answer.